# Symfony Order entities by field OneToMany

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

Who knows how to solved this simple question? 
I have entity project with field likedUsers and in twig count up this field but I want order projects by this count up (DESC) - first who have more likedUsers. How to do it? In query builder or in twig create filter?Help with doctrine I know count

```
"likes_user" => count($this->getLikedUsers()->getValues())
```

how to sort my all projects from this field?

or how its solved with query builder? 
something like that, but this is not work:

```
public function getProjects()
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('d');
    $qb
        ->select('d')
        ->from('AppBundle:Project', 'd')
        ->where('d.confirm = :identifier')
        ->setParameter('identifier', 'approved')
        ->orderBy('COUNT(d.likedUsers)', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $results = $query->getResult();
    return $results;
}
```

entity:

```
/**
 * Project
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\ProjectRepository")
 */
class Project implements \JsonSerializable
{
    /**
     * @var Collection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="likedProjects")
     */
    private $likedUsers;




{% for project in projects %}
<div>LIked: <span>{{ project.likedUsers|length|number_format(0, '.', ' ') }}</span></div>
{% endfor %}
```

I think maybe like that:

```
{% for project in projects.likedUsers|length|sort %}
```

but not effect
maybe who knows? How array projects sort by count of field LikedUser. I don’t know how do this. Query builder or twig extension or usort..

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, this seems like a job for `PHP` instead of `Doctrine`. Not sure if t could be achieved by `Doctrine` and, if possible, what would be an impact.

One way to do this is [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

```
$projects = ...;
usort($projects, function($p1, $p2){ 
    // Both $p1 and $p2 are instance of Project
    // Assuming that `getLikedUsers()` return Doctrine `Collection`...

    return count($p1->getLikedUsers()) > count($p2->getLikedUsers());
});
```

`usort` takes an array and in each pass offers two items (two projects in your case) for you to decide which one is "greater". In your case, the project with more likes is definitely "greater", right?

Hope this helps...

Comment: update my question. I not understand what about $p1, $p2 and size() ? maybe count($project->getLikedUser()->getValues()) or I not understand

Comment: If I get this right, you have a list of *projects* and you need to sort these by  count of "likedUsers". Is that correct?

Comment: Good :) I have updated the answer... You do not pass `$p1` and `$p2`... `usort` does that for you...

Comment: but I have $projects = array() what is it function($p1, $p2) ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96894/discussion-between-shuba-ivan-and-jovan-perovic).

Answer (score 0):

I solved with query builder. And I add only project who have like user - user live in some city no all city

```
public function getProject()
{
    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('d');
    $qb
        ->select('d')
        ->from('AppBundle:Project', 'd')
        ->addSelect('COUNT(m.id) as nMethods')
        ->join('d.likedUsers', 'm')
        ->join('m.location', 'l')
        ->where('l.city = :identifier')
        ->setParameter('identifier', 'someCity')
        ->groupBy('d.id')
        ->orderBy("nMethods", 'DESC')

        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult()
    ;
    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $results = $query->getResult();
    return $results;
}
```